# Show all routes from one next-hop via CLI

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

I'm running into what should be a very easy problem to solve- I need to see all routes coming from one specific next-hop on a few cisco ASR 1002-X's that I have in my network. Normally this should be as easy as a `| inc x.x.x.x` filter on `show ip route`, but all of the output is coming up on two lines due to the length of the interface names, making the filter useless. Here is some example output:

```
<Router>#sh ip route 

<legend omitted>    

D*EX  0.0.0.0/0 [170/51968] via 10.x.x.58, 7w0d, GigabitEthernet0/2/0.140
      10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 294 subnets, 13 masks 
D EX     10.x.x.23/32 
           [170/5120] via 10.x.x.78, 5w1d, GigabitEthernet0/2/0.142 
D        10.x.x.0/24 
           [90/3584] via 10.x.x.58, 2w3d, GigabitEthernet0/2/0.140 
D        10.x.x.0/13 
           [90/4864] via 10.x.x.68, 7w0d, GigabitEthernet0/2/0.141 
D        10.x.x.0/30 
           [90/4608] via 10.x.x.68, 7w0d, GigabitEthernet0/2/0.141 
D        10.x.x.4/30 
           [90/5376] via 10.x.x.58, 7w0d, GigabitEthernet0/2/0.140 
D        10.x.x.253/32 
           [90/133120] via 10.x.x.58, 7w0d, GigabitEthernet0/2/0.140 
D        10.x.x.254/32 
           [90/132352] via 10.x.x.68, 7w0d, GigabitEthernet0/2/0.141 
D        10.x.x.0/14 
           [90/3328] via 10.x.x.58, 7w0d, GigabitEthernet0/2/0.140
...<etc>
```

No matter what I do (including increasing the terminal width to 256 chars), the output is always on two lines, removing the ability to use the pipe/inc filter. I'm aware I can redirect to file, copy to my desktop, and then start doing some manual searching via a text editor, but that is all very time-consuming when I'm in the middle of troubleshooting an issue.

**Is there a way to filter a list of all routes on a router by next-hop IP, even when the next-hop IP is displayed on the second line of output of `show ip route`?**

Comment: Instead of `show ip route`, does `show ip rib route` give you what you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately, output from 'show ip rib route` is also split onto two lines.

Comment: When I run that command, it fits everything on a single line, even with very long `GigabitEthernetx/x/x.xxx` interface names. The `show ip rib route` shows what in the RIB, and `show ip cef` shows what's in the FIB, in a very compressed format, just `Prefix   Next Hop    Interface`.

Comment: Filtering on `show ip cef` works! That produces a much more compact list that all fits onto single lines. Post an answer and I'll accept it, thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at routes in multiple ways.

The `show ip rib route` command shows what's in the RIB like `show ip route`, and I suppose it depends on the IOS version, but I see `show ip rib route` output on single lines where `show ip route` shows output on two lines.

The `show ip cef` command shows what's in the FIB, in a very compressed format, just `Prefix Next Hop Interface`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `show ip route | sec X.X.X.X`? The section option should provide more output than the single line inc option.

Comment: That produces the same output as using `| inc x.x.x.x`- it doesn't include the preceding line with the route.